# Закрашивание поверхности в Python

Tags: python, gui

Есть цилиндр

```
x=np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
z=np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
Xc, Zc=np.meshgrid(x, z)
Yc = np.sqrt(1-Xc**2)
rstride = 20
cstride = 10
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2,linewidth=0)
ax.plot_surface(Xc, -Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2,linewidth=0)
```

Также есть список точек, которые нужно перекрасить. Каким образом можно это сделать? Может есть подходящая функция?

Нашел возможность раскрасить, но почему-то некорректно закрашивается задняя сторона цилиндра

```
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#Построение цилиндра
x=np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
z=np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
Xc, Zc=np.meshgrid(x, z)
Yc = np.sqrt(1-Xc**2)

############################
# Create light source object.
ls = LightSource(azdeg=0, altdeg=65)
# Shade data, creating an rgb array.
rgb = ls.shade(Yc, plt.cm.RdYlBu)

############################

rstride = 20
cstride = 10
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc,facecolors=rgb, alpha=0.9,linewidth=0)
ax.plot_surface(Xc, -Yc, Zc,facecolors=rgb, alpha=0.9,linewidth=0)

ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")

plt.show()
```

Comment: вы можете привести пример точек и пояснить как их нужно перекрасить?

Comment: Нужно создать простой источник света. Я решлил делать через нормаль поверхности в каждой точке и лучом(который задаётся точкой и направляющим вектором). После этого ищу углы между векторами нормали и лучем. Осталось понять с помощью чего менять цвет. Тк есть точки и "коэффициенты"изменения цвета

Comment: А matplotlib.colors.LightSource не подходит для вашей задачи?

Comment: @Avernial Вообще подходит, только почему-то задняя сторона не до конца черным закрашивается, не понимаю почему

Comment: @Avernial добавил код в первый пост